# Mess-up my android design not same as i design

Tags: android, user-interface

I run my android application in max 10 devices where some devices run my application exactly the same as I design but some devices struggle. This problem comes to my Tablayout, during swiping right to left or vice-versa Can anyone tell me, what the exact problem is?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW1Lq.jpg)

Comment: Your are not being specific with your issue, what does actually happen when you swipe .
Oh and, the image does not really tell anything , so far it seems to be from the same phone, Edit your question and added details of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SDP library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp). It is easy to use and support multiple devices like mobile and tablet. If you don't want to use 3rd party library then design the multiple dimens/layout folder to support multiple screen size devices.